# drawBitmap where one pixel equals one pixel

Tags: android

If I draw a bitmap on a view canvas using drawBitmap(), the images will be resampled so that 1 pixel in the image will be 1 dip on the screen. On a device I have with high pixel density, that means each image pixel is spread across 1.5 screen pixels, degrading the image.  Handy in general, but in some cases I want to carefully select the images I want to draw, then draw them explicitly at their native size, so they won't degrade.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResource, R.drawable.resource, opts);
```

alternatively you could store your resources inside a res/drawable-nodpi folder

Comment: I'm not getting correct results with either of those.  It still does the exact same thing.  Is there anything else I have to do?  BTW I did bump the API to a 1.6 so it would support inScaled -- which I don't like but I suppose I can do something like this: http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/190539066/android-unscaled-bitmaps